# How to check if current time falls in between startTime and endTime in Groovy

Tags: grails, groovy

How to check if currentTime is in between startTime and endTime. Unfortunately my domain class has to use startTime and endTime as Strings.

Update:

statTime is just time e.g. 6.00
endTime is just time eg 18:00

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well the obvious approach is to parse both strings into whatever date/time representation you like (personally I prefer [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net)) and then compare the current date/time with that. Have you tried that? Where have you become unstuck? If the problem is that they're *times* rather than *date/time* values, Joda Time's [`LocalTime`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/LocalTime.html) class is what you want. (It's not clear why your *domain* representation needs to be strings, by the way - you should make your domain representation the most natural one, and convert it to/from text representations at boundaries where you absolutely have to, IMO.)

I would strongly advise you *not* to use some sort of static call to obtain the current date and time. Instead, use dependency injection to inject a "current time service" as you would any other dependency - you can then unit test this with a "fake clock" which is controlled in the tests, and inject a real implementation (which could use `System.currentTimeMillis` or whatever you want) for production.

Answer (score 3):

Parse startTime and endTime to Dates and then `currentTime in startTime..endTime`

Answer (score 0):

Use Groovy [java.util.Date.parse(String format, String input)](http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#parse%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) to parse the string to a *java.util.Date* and then compare *currentTime* with *Date.before()* and *Date.after()*. Use *Date.getTime()* to convert to unix timestamp as *long* if necessary.